# IBM DSX Local : ImportError: No module named project_lib

Tags: python, data-science-experience, dsx-local

I am trying to use the IBM DSX built-in package "project_lib" but got the error "No module named project_lib". The package is for accessing the assets (i.e. files) of my projects. I am using IBM DSX local, not sure if the package is available for the "local" version.

I tried to ask questions on IBM's website or customer services but could not find the contact information.

```
from project_lib import Project;
project = Project(None, '**************', '**************');
pc = project.project_context;
```

It would be appreciated very much if you could provide some help or information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `project_lib` is not available for DSX Local. It's available in Watson Studio on Cloud notebooks, in Watson Studio Local 2.0, and I think also in the latest Watson Studio Desktop.

The package relies on some internal information about the environments in which it is made available. Therefore, you can only use it in those supported environments.

DSX Local has a different library for similar purposes. It's called [`dsx_core_utils`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/search/dsx_core_utils?scope=SSAS34_1.2.0).